# How do you scroll up/down on the console of a Linux VM

Tags: linux, terminal, rhel

I recognize that <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> will give you the command history. But, how do you look at past output by scrolling up and down?

I have used <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> but none of these seem to work.

It is a Redhat Linux box.

Comment: Are you using an xterm (or equivalent)?

Comment: no redhat enterprise linux

Comment: I mean how are you accessing the shell. Which terminal emulator?

Comment: I am just accessing the linux server from a VM console.

Comment: Is that a vmware thing? If you're not using a regular terminal emulator, you won't have terminal functions like scrollback.

Comment: I guess it makes a difference whether Jane Doh is looking at an X session with gnome terminals or the actual console output that comes as text to a "VM Console Screen"  Ancient history here, at 2013, but it's an interesting question over all.

Answer (score 272):

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>. If it doesn't work try this and then it should:

Go the terminal program, and make sure
`Edit/Profile Preferences/Scrolling/Scrollback/Unlimited`
is checked.

The exact location of this option might be somewhere different though, I see that you are using Redhat.

Comment: That would be a completely different question. OP was talking about stuff like gnome terminal

Comment: Cool, thanks! How would you go about setting the scrollback size from a native ('real') terminal?

Comment: Only the first line of this answer is useful on the Linux console, the rest *might* be useful on a GUI terminal like gnome-terminal, though unlimited is not needed.

Comment: @GringoSuave gets it.

Comment: For those of you who didn't find it work, don't forget to turn `NumLock` off

Answer (score 131):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+ <kbd>UP</kbd> or <kbd>DOWN</kbd> on a Macbook will allow you to scroll.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for for Ubuntu Server.  Thanks!

Comment: Works well on CentOS vm in Mac host

Comment: Thank you. Works for me (Ubuntu Server inside VirtualBox VM on Mac OSX10.10)

Comment: Thanks for this Lauren, and thanks @anizzomc.  I was on my macbook pro running Ubuntu server in virtual box and was having a heck of a time trying to figure this out.

Comment: Shift + Ctrl + Up / Down works for me on Ubuntu laptop

Comment: As the comments show, this is the only correct answer. Everyone else is talking about terminal emulators, which is not what the OP is asking. It is the only thing which worked for me on Ubuntu Server 14.04 emulation in Parallels on Macbook Pro

Comment: I Would love to hear from the OP on this answer.  Shift Pg-UP and Shift pg-Down are the canonical answer which are documented not to work in VMware, so maybe this doesn't work either...

Comment: that's simply because your PageUp/PageDown keys are mapped to Fn+Up/Down, it won't work in other keyboards. And Fn is not a real key that the OS recognizes (except on Macs)

Answer (score 90):

**Alternative:**   you can use the `less` command.

Type in console:

```
"your_command" | less
```

This will allow you to scroll with the up and down arrow keys.

Basically your output has been piped with the `less` command.

Comment: Interesting enough this was the only way that actually worked when using the shell on a FreeNAS install disk.

Comment: FreeNAS is FreeBSD based, and there you scroll differently. First you press `scroll lock` to get into paging mode and then use plain arrows and `page up`/`page down` to scroll. Press `scroll lock` again to get back to typing mode.

Comment: This is the only solution that works on headless servers. Other solutions are for servers with GUI.

Answer (score 28):

**ALTERNATIVE FOR LINE-BY-LINE SCROLLING**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>

Unlike <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, which scrolls the entire page, this will help with a smoother line-by-line scrolling, which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I needed scrolling for a Chromebook which doesn’t have `Page Up` and `Page Down`. Works well.

Comment: Believe this requires `CONFIG_VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK` to be enabled on the linux console.

Answer (score 25):

`SHIFT + Page Up` and `SHIFT + Page Down` are the correct keys to operate on the linux (virtual) console, but vmware console doesn't have those terminal settings.  The virtual console has fixed scroll back size, it sounds like it's limited to video memory size according to this Linux virtual console [*Scrolling behavior documentation.*](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-18.html)

Comment: In order to prevent the Matthew Effect, from now on I will try to upvote the second and correct answer to encourage ppl to answer the questions who already have a correct answer.

Comment: Does this mean that VMWare intercepts those keystrokes?

Answer (score 19):

Another alternative, that might be already installed on your system is to use GNU screen :

```
# This starts screen which adds basic window management in terminals
screen

# This starts the copy mode you can use to scroll
<CTRL-A> [

# Now use the arrows to scroll

# To exit copy mode, do
<ESC>
```

See man screen for much more useful options (multiple windows, ...)...

Answer (score 13):

Shift Pageup/End works for me.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I cant comment yet :(

Answer (score 10):

It seems as though this is not easily possible: The [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_shortcuts) lists no way to do this on the console (while easily possible on the virtual terminal).

You could use [tmux scrolling](https://superuser.com/questions/209437/how-do-i-scroll-in-tmux):

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> then <kbd>[</kbd> then you can use your normal navigation keys to scroll around (eg. <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>PgDn</kbd>). Press <kbd>q</kbd> to quit scroll mode.
>
> Alternatively you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>PgUp</kbd> to go directly into copy mode and scroll one page up (which is what it sounds like you will want most of the time)

Answer (score 8):

VM Ubuntu on a Mac...fn + shift + up/down arrows

Comment: this is [exactly the same as Lauren's answer above, but with the OS mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20019785/995714)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem with VMWare workstation with Ubuntu guest, turns out VmWare doesn't support scrolling back up from the server view. What I did was to install x GUI, then run xterm from there. For some reason it runs the same, but lets you scroll the normal ways. Hope this helps future readers in VmWare virtual boxes.

Comment: Heavyweight solution.  Another might be to install sshd and log in remotely.

Answer (score 3):

In some VPS hostings (like `linode`) you have to click <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> and then <kbd>ESC</kbd>. Exit with double `ESC` too.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Up/Down</kbd> can scroll Terminal in Mac OS X 10.11

Answer (score 1):

Press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when scrolling the mouse up/down works for me when loggin in Ubuntu using Terminal `ssh` in Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

**PERSISTENT, longterm solution**

Add this line to your `~/.screenrc`

```
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
```

> Now you can create a screen, and scroll it up/down with your mouse;
> Like you normally do.

Comment: Where do you see OP talking about `screen`? This should be removed.

Comment: @Atralb if you think an answer is inappropriate you can downvote or flag it ;) no offense Slake that solution was probably helpful for you, but indeed does not really fit here

Answer (score 0):

For some commands, such as mtr + (plus) and - (minus) work to scroll up and down.